# Como alterar o value de um custom attribute?

Tags: html, jquery, data-attribute

Estou querendo alterar o value de um custom attr via jquery, porém sem sucesso. Segue o código abaixo:

```js
$("#botao-01").click(function() {
    $("#img-screen").attr("data-image","img/bauru-02.jpg");
 });
```

```html
<div id="img-screen" class="tile" data-scale="2.4" data-image="img/bauru-01.jpg" alt="Equipamento 01"></div>
```

O que eu quero é quando clicar em um selector ele alterar a imagem que foi setada via data-image mais tudo isso via jquery.

Já tentei inúmeras opções mais sem sucesso até o momento... alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

O seu código deveria funcionar corretamente, tanto que se você der um console.log logo após a alteração do atributo irá notar que o valor foi alterado em *runtime*.

```js
$("#botao-01").click(function() {
    $("#img-screen").attr("data-image","img/bauru-02.jpg");
    console.log($("#img-screen").attr("data-image"));
 });
```

```html
<div id="img-screen" class="tile" data-scale="2.4" data-image="img/bauru-01.jpg" alt="Equipamento 01"></div>
```

Outra maneira de alterar é fazer assim `$("#img-screen").data("image","img/bauru-02.jpg");`

Porém eu estou suspeitando que você tenha um outro script/plugin rodando na página, algo que use o data-scale para transformar a sua imagem. Caso seja isso mesmo, sempre que você alterar o data-image você deve **rodar novamente** o plugin/script que depende do valor data-image para funcionar.